Reference for $\epsilon$-regularity
I am looking for a reference for the following $\epsilon$-regularity statement: let

$(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$,
$\Delta=dd^*+d^*d$,
$B_r$ denotes a ball of radius $r$ around a fixed point in $M.$

Then $\exists\epsilon>0,C\leq\infty$ such that if $f$ is a non-negative function satisfying the inequality
$$
\Delta f\leq f^2,
$$ then we have
$$
\|f\|_{L^{\frac{n}{2}}(B_{\frac{r}{2}})}\leq\epsilon\implies\|f\|_{L^\infty(B_\frac{r}{2})}\leq C\|f\|_{L^{\frac{n}{2}}(B_r)}
$$
Note, the $n=4$ case is given here.

It seems that the  set  of  functions satisfying $\Delta f\leq f^2$ can not be  very  big. Because your question remind me of  a theorem  of  Grothendieck  which says :  if  $|.|_{\infty}$  is  dominated by $|.|_2 $ on a a  subspace  of  $L^{\infty}\cap \ell^2$ then  the  subspace  is necessarily a  finite  dimensional space

on the  other hand the  condition $\Delta f\leq f^2 $ is preserved by  "addition"

So  for  a  compact Riemannian manifold a  natural  question is to  assign  an upper  bound  for  the  maximum number of independent positive  functions  $f_1, f_2,\ldots,f_n$   with $\Delta f_i \leq f_i^2$

@AliTaghavi I do not see the connection between $\Delta f \leq f^2$ and Grothendieck's result, other than the presence of an inequality and something being squared. How is Grothendieck's result relevant to what the OP is actually asking about?

@YemonChoi the domination of norm infinity by norm-2. A result attributed to Grothendieck. I found it in Royden real analysis.

@YemonChoi it is a little strange:for small disk the positive solutions of the inequality span a finite dimension but in big disk thy produce infinite dim space(according to Gabe comment on my recently deleted question). Any way the set of solutions is a lattice invariant under $\lambda$ rescalling $\lambda\geq 1$

First, it is straightforward to adapt Haslhofer's proof to higher dimensions, using the Sobolev inequality: For any compactly supported $u$ such that $\|\nabla u\|_2 < \infty$,
$$ \|u\|_{\frac{2n}{n-2}} \le C\|\nabla u\|_2. $$
I encourage you to try.
If you google epsilon regularity, you’ll find several explanations of it, including anther Math Overflow questionn.
The beauty of this simple and elegant proof is that it does not require coordinates and the dependence of the constant in the inequality on the geometry of the manifold is purely through the Sobolev constant.
There must be other good references for this, but it is proved in Appendix B of my paper:
Convergence of riemannian manifolds with integral bounds on curvature. II
Annales scientifiques de l’É.N.S. 4e série, tome 25, no 2 (1992), p. 179-199
